# saving a picture with the RGB values in Python with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to create a program that needs to save pictures with the RGB values. This is just a simple test I've set up to make sure I can open, get the data, then save the image with the data again:

```
inputIm = Image.open(args.target)

#denoises image and saves it to disk
#data = DenoiseImage(inputIm, factor, iters)
data = np.array(inputIm.getdata())
n, m = inputIm.size
print data
outputIm = Image.new("RGB", (n, m))
outputIm.putdata(data)
outputIm.save(args.fileName)
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DenoiseNumpyWeave.py", line 253, in <module>
    outputIm.putdata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1215, in putdata
    self.im.putdata(data, scale, offset)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

However, the print data line DOES print out an array with tuples in it, so I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. I've done the exact same thing with black/white pictures ("L" instead of "RGB"), and put in an array without tuples (single values instead), and that worked.

Comment: Looks like `putdata` doesn't accept numpy arrays. Try converting it into a regular list first.

Comment: @kevin I tried to do this: `data2 = list(data)` then I used data2 in putdata, but that didn't work. Same error.

Comment: @kevin also tried to do `data2 = data.tolist()`, instead of list(data), same result. That said, doing `data2 = list(inputIm.getdata())` DOES work... But I can't do that as I need a numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy has converted the tuples provided by `getdata` into arrays. You need to convert them back to tuples for `putdata` to work.

```
outputIm.putdata([tuple(pixel) for pixel in data])
```

Comment: This throws me this error: http://pastebin.com/4SWXASy8
Your idea sounds good, though.

Comment: @user2875994 you need parentheses after `tuple`, not square brackets. Try copy/pasting the line from my answer.

Comment: @user2875994 then why does the error message on pastebin show square brackets? And in case I wasn't clear, it's `tuple(pixel)` not `tuple[pixel]`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'm an idiot. That said, it still throws an error, let me mess for a second and then I'll post the error

Comment: Actually, found out what caused that, earlier declaration was changed up for when I was testing something. Fixed that. Thanks, golden answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your black-and-white image had a single channel ("L") so an n-by-m array worked just fine.  An RGB image has 3 channels though, so you may need an n-by-m-by-3 array.

Comment: Huh? When I used ("L"), I had a 1-dimensional array with single values in them (e.g. n array, not n by m, if I understood what you meant correctly). The array I'm trying to use here is n by 3, if, again, I understood you correctly.

Comment: @user2875994 I think what he means is that Numpy flattened the `n*m` 3-tuples coming from `getdata` into a single `n*m*3` array. You need to unflatten it back.

Comment: @MarkRansom getdata already flattens it, so that shouldn't be the case. It's never a 3-dimensional structure to begin with.

Comment: @user2875994 no it's not 3D, but it is 2D. And I was wrong, a quick test shows it's not flattening but the 2nd dimension is numpy arrays, not tuples.

Comment: @MarkRansom Erm, a quick test does show flattening, you just have to do getdata then print it. Yeah it's an array of arrays (because it has to store R, G and B values for each pixel), or whatever, but it's not n*m. E.g. array[x][y] wont let you access anything. If you read the documentation, it even says "The sequence object is flattened".